# Ember : Could not find module `@ember-intl/intl-relativeformat` imported from `ember-intl/services/intl`

Tags: ember.js, internationalization, intl, ember-intl

I added the module **ember-intl** in my app since the **ember-i18n** is deprecated.
so yarn works well, updates package.json and yarn.lock (i got rid of the package.lock),
but i get this error on the browser's console after a successful ember build:

> Error: Could not find module `@ember-intl/intl-relativeformat`
>   imported from `ember-intl/services/intl`

But in my **node_modules** the folders @ember-intl/intl-relativeformat and ember-intl both exist.
in the yarn.lock i have this line:
"@ember-intl/intl-relativeformat@^2.1.0":

more info:

> Ember         : 3.5.1
>   Ember Data    : 3.5.0
>   jQuery        : 3.3.1
>   Ember Remodal : 2.18.0

Comment: I attempted to reproduce this problem from a fresh install using `ember 3.5.1`, `ember-cli 3.5.0`, `ember-intl 3.5.0`, and `ember-cli-babel 6.17.2`. I did `ember new`, followed by yarn install, and then injected the service into a route and successsfully logged a computed property's value in the model hook (the property performed a translation). Are you using the latest for ember cli and ember cli babel? Inability to find modules is generally related to these two libraries from my experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding [`ember-auto-import`](https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import) to my project. It comes pre-installed in new Ember projects, but needs to be added manually to older ones.

Just run `ember install ember-auto-import` and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed it to see if a blank slate would show me that error.

It did not. : /

*I just had a few beers*... but I just want to make sure you *imported* the service.

the docs show:

```
// app/routes/application.js
export default Route.extend({
  intl: service(),
  beforeModel() {
    return this.intl.setLocale(['fr-fr', 'en-us']); /* array optional */
  }
});
```

*but like most docs* - assume you know the larger ecosystem. It's a tiny possibility that you might not have imported the module *above* `import Service from '@ember/service';` etc.? https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/services/

if not that... then track down the mentioned 'ember-intl/services/intl' and see if you can figure out why the '@ember-intl/intl-relativeformat' import isn't jiving. Maybe check the repo and the version - and ask there on GitHub?

Good luck!

Comment: thanks, i verified as you mentionned the imports are here, the service is set, also tried to install package in a fresh ember-cli new app, but cannot reprocude the same problem.